# "User matching query does not exist" occurring in template but not in unit test?

Tags: python, sql, django, database

In a Django project, there is a `Family` model defined similar to the following:

```
class Family(BaseFamily):
    employee_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    employee_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    partner_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    partner_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

where `BaseFamily` has a `package` and `lucy_guide` foreign key:

```
class BaseFamily(TimeStampedModel):
    package = models.ForeignKey('lucy_web.Package',
                                models.SET_NULL,
                                blank=True,
                                null=True)
    lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='lucy_guide_%(class)s',
        limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
```

The `Package` model, in turn, is linked to a `Company`:

```
class Package(TimeStampedModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey('lucy_web.Company')
```

and a `Company`, in turn, has a `lucy_guide` and a `default_package`:

```
class Company(TimeStampedModel):
    lucy_guide = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='lucy_guide_%(class)s',
        limit_choices_to={'is_staff': True})
    default_package = models.OneToOneField(
        Package,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='default_for_%(class)s')
```

Now, I have a template which uses the following template tag, `edit_view_family_heading`:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag
def edit_view_family_heading(family):
    heading = [family.employee_first_name]

    if family.employee_last_name != family.partner_last_name:
        heading.append(family.employee_last_name)

    heading.extend([
        '&',
        family.partner_first_name,
        family.partner_last_name
    ])

    heading = [e for e in heading if e]

    if heading[0] == '&':
        heading.pop(0)

    if heading and heading[-1] == '&':
        heading.pop()

    if heading:
        if family.lucy_guide:
            heading.append(f'({family.lucy_guide.first_name})')

        return ' '.join(heading)
    else:
        return family.id
```

However, if I try to display the template, I get the following error:

```
Template error:
In template /Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/dashboard/templates/dashboard.html, error at line 0
   User matching query does not exist.   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : {% load sass_tags %}
   3 : {% load compress %}
   4 : {% load google_analytics %}
   5 : {% load active_page %}
   6 : 
   7 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   8 : <html lang="en">
   9 : <head>
   10 :   <title>Cleo Admin | {% block page_title %}{% endblock %}</title>


Traceback:

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  178.             rel_obj = getattr(instance, self.cache_name)

During handling of the above exception ('Family' object has no attribute '_lucy_guide_cache'), another exception occurred:

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  107.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  84.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  207.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  177.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  72.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  990.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  957.             return self.render(context)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/library.py" in render
  203.         output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/dashboard/templatetags/edit_view_family_heading.py" in edit_view_family_heading
  28.         if family.lucy_guide:

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in __get__
  184.                 rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py" in get_object
  159.         return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))

File "/Users/kurtpeek/Documents/Dev/lucy2/lucy-web/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  380.                 self.model._meta.object_name

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /dashboard/families/763/case-management
Exception Value: User matching query does not exist.
```

I've tried to narrow down the problem with these unit tests, but they all pass:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

from dashboard.tests.utils import AccountMixin
from dashboard.templatetags.edit_view_family_heading import edit_view_family_heading
from lucy_web.test_factories import FamilyFactory, UserFactory
from lucy_web.models import Family


class FamilyEditTest(TestCase, AccountMixin):
    def setUp(self):
        self.login_user(UserFactory(is_superuser=True))

    def test_case_management_with_lucy_guide_defined(self):
        family = FamilyFactory()
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('dashboard:family', kwargs={'pk': family.id, 'tab': 'case-management'}))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'families/edit.html')

    def test_case_management_without_lucy_guide_defined(self):
        family = Family()
        family.save()

        self.assertIs(family.lucy_guide, None)

        response = self.client.get(
            reverse('dashboard:family', kwargs={'pk': family.id, 'tab': 'case-management'}))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'families/edit.html')


class TestFamilyHeading(TestCase):
    def test_edit_view_family_heading(self):
        family = FamilyFactory(
            employee_first_name="Shannon",
            employee_last_name="Spanhake",
            partner_first_name="Aaron",
            partner_last_name="Levie",
            lucy_guide=UserFactory(first_name="Rebekah"))
        heading = edit_view_family_heading(family)
        self.assertEqual(
            heading,
            "Shannon Spanhake & Aaron Levie (Rebekah)")

    def test_edit_view_family_heading_no_lucy_guide(self):
        family = FamilyFactory(package=None)
        self.assertIs(family.lucy_guide, None)
        heading = edit_view_family_heading(family)
        self.assertEqual(
            heading,
            f"{family.employee_first_name} {family.employee_last_name} & "
            f"{family.partner_first_name} {family.partner_last_name}")
```

In other words, the view is using the correct template and the template tag behaves as expected when tested as a regular function, even if the family has no `lucy_guide`.

I suspect that my database is in a 'weird' state and that somewhere in this interlinked chain of models something is missing, but I'm struggling to narrow down on what. Any suggestions to debug this error?

**Update**

Looking at the database (with pgAdmin 4), it would appear that the `Family` in question has a `lucy_guide_id`:

[image]

However, there is no row in the `auth_user` table corresponding to this `id`:

[image]

I suspect that this has to do with the `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` option for the `package` foreign key, but I don't see anything in the documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) that indicates that any of the options would allow the database to get into such a 'corrupted' state.

Any ideas how the database got into this state, and how I could reproduce this error in a unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up putting the call to `family.lucy_guide` in a `try` .. `except` block:

```
    try:
        if family.lucy_guide:
            heading.append(f'({family.lucy_guide.first_name})')
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
```

where `ObjectDoesNotExist` is imported from `django.core.exceptions`. The page now loads normally.